Using Karate || How to count number of instances of a string when js file is in response?
I have an API to get js file from blob in response and I need to check an element in the js that may occur multiple times.
I tried using "contains" but it does not tell me the total number of occurences but the fact that js has the element.
How can I get the total number of its instances?

you mean JS and not JSON ? then contains won't work. please edit your question and give a simple example of what the response is, else no one can answer this
